# Batch resize images into new folder using ImageMagick

Tags: image, bash, imagemagick, filesize

I have a folder of images over `4MB` - let's call this folder `dsc_big/`. I'd like to use `convert -define jpeg:extent=2MB` to convert them to under `2MB` and copy `dsc_big/*` to a folder `dsc_small/` that already exists.

I tried `convert dsc_big/* -define jpeg:extent=2MB dsc_small/` but that produces images called `-0`, `-1`, and so on.

What do I do?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`convert` is designed to handle a single input file as far as I can tell, although I have to admit I don't understand the output you're getting. [mogrify](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify) is better suited for batch processing in the following style:

```
mogrify -path ../dsc_small -define jpeg:extent=2MB dsc_big/*
```

But honestly I consider it dangerous for general usage (it'll overwrite the original images if you forget that `-path`) so I always use `convert` coupled with a for loop for this:

```
for file in dsc_big/*; do convert $file -define jpeg:extent=2MB dsc_small/`basename $file`; done
```

The `basename` call isn't necessary if you're processing files in the current directory.

Comment: Also how can I do this with `mogrify`?

Comment: ImageMagick 6.8.0 can handle muliple files with convert: `convert *.jpg *.png`. However I don't know how to handle the output file names, because ImageMagick just set the name to a sequential number (i.e.:1.png, 2.png, 3.png, and so on)

Comment: The "-path" in mogrify seems to have been deprecated. An updated example would be great. http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php

Answer (score 5):

This was the command which helped me after a long try.
I wanted to make same sized thumbnails from a big list of large images which have variable width and height . It was for creating a gallery page.

```
convert -define jpeg:size=250x200 *.jpg  -thumbnail 250x200^ -gravity center -extent 250x200  crop/thumbnail-%d.jpeg
```

I got re-sized thumbnails which all having same width and height. :) thanks to ImageMagick.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution **without** using for loops on the console

```
convert *.jpeg -define jpeg:extent=2MB -set filename:f '../dsc_small/%t_small.%e' +adjoin '%[filename:f]'
```

Answer (score 2):

Although this is an old question, but I'm adding this response for the benefit of anyone else that stumbles upon this.

I had the same exact issue, and being discouraged by the use of `mogrify`, I wrote a small Python based utility called [easymagick](https://github.com/danishm/easymagick) to make this process easier while internally using the `convert` command.

Please note, this is still a work in progress. I'll appreciate any kind of feedback I can get.

Answer (score 1):

I found that `cd`-ing into the desired folder, and then using the bash global variable `$PWD` made my `convert` not throw any errors. I'm utilizing ImageMagick's recently implemented `caption:` http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#caption function to label my images with the base filename and place them in another directory within the first.

```
cd ~/person/photos
mkdir labeled
for f in $PWD/*.JPG; do
    width=$(identify -format %w $f)
    filename=$(basename $f .JPG)
convert -background '#0008' -colorspace transparent -fill white -gravity center -size ${width}x100  caption:"${filename}" ${f} +swap -gravity south -composite "$PWD/labeled/${filename}.jpg";
done
```

Comment: Consider using `"$f"` rather than `$f` in the lines starting `width=...` and `filename=...` in case there are filenames with spaces in them.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
convert -rotate 90 *.png rotate/image.jpg
```

produces image-0.jpg, image-1.jpg, image-2.jpg ..... in the 'rotate' folder. Don't know of a way to preserve the original filenames though.

Comment: Use `mogrify -path rotate -rotate 90 *.png`